# How to compile gfortran using Canopy

Tags: python, fortran, enthought, canopy

I have the Enthought Canopy 1.5.4 Distribution installed on a MacBook Pro that I use for Python. I also have a gfortran compiler installed.  How do I run the fortran compiler from the Canopy GUI?

Comment: Do you have to run the fortran compiler from the Canopy GUI? would it be possible to create a virtualenv using the standard python distribution that uses the fortran compiler. I know virtualenv allows you to use the -p flag to specify particular compilers on your macine e.g. `virtualenv -p /Users/brendan/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python canopy`

Comment: You can't literally run the f compiler from Canopy GUI (except in the most obvious manual way, namely as a shell command at the ipython prompt). Or is it that you actually want to build a fortran extension to run in Canopy Python?